# Angular: Combine the functionality of AsyncSubject and BehaivorSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs

User in my application can have list of car and can make one car as active. After login proccess I make request to the server and get the active car. Also, when user logged in already(token has not expired) and open app(or refresh page via F5) I also load active car from the server. The prblem is I have a lot of placces where I need to use `currentCar`. The first obvious solution is to use `BehaviorSubject`. So, in my service I have:

```
public currentCar$: BehaviorSubject<Car> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

Then, in the constructor, I get data and assign value to the `currentCar$`.

Then, in some components I use it:

```
 this.carService.currentCar$
      .subscribe(car=> {
        if(car) {//do what we need}      
}
```

I use this code a lot in my components and I always have to check if car is defined(request has finished) or not(default null value).
So, I want to wait until request has finished, for this case I can use `AsyncSubject`. And it works fine, but, I as I said, user has UI where he can change current car. After changing I need to assign new value to `currentCar$`,  but `next` doesn't do anything, because the `AsynSubject` must be completed when request has been finished. So, I need some combination of `AsyncSubject` and `BehaivorSubject`. Is there some operators maybe or another way?

PS. I can't use local storage, data always must be loaded from server.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you could use `ReplaySubject(1)` chained with `take(1)` instead.

In you case it'll work the same way as `BehaviorSubject` but all observer will wait until it emits at least one item. If you subscribe later that the latest value is going to ba cached by `ReplaySubject`.

```
public currentCar$ = new ReplaySubject<Car>(1);
```

Then when you want to access car you'll always call:

```
this.carService.currentCar$.take(1)
  .subscribe(car=> {
     ...
  })
```